# Négation introduite par « pas moins de »

Tags: négation, comparatifs, emphase

Prenons l'exemple suivant :

> L'entreprise a déposé **pas** moins de 745 brevets cette année.

Est-ce correct ? Ne devrait-on pas plutôt écrire :

> L'entreprise **n'** a **pas** déposé moins de 745 brevets cette année.

Je trouve étrange que le premier exemple ne contienne pas le mot ***ne*** (ou ***n'***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En disant "**pas moins de 745 brevets**", on dit que l'entreprise a déposé **exactement** 745 brevets, et on met l'accent sur le fait que c'est beaucoup (sous entendu, "on pourrait penser que c'est moins, mais en fait c'est 745 !").

En disant "**n'a pas déposé moins de 745 brevets**", on ne connait pas le nombre exact de brevets déposés, et cette formulation serait utilisé dans un contexte où il y aurait un seuil.
Par exemple (supposons que ç'ait du sens) si un prix était décerné à toutes les entreprises qui déposent au moins 745 brevets, on dirait "L'entreprise n'a pas déposé moins de 745 brevets [, ce qui lui permet de remporter le prix]".
Ici, le sous entendu est donc inverse par rapport à la première formulation, ici, le sous entendu serait "Vous dites qu'ils n'ont pas déposés assez de brevets pour remporter le prix, mais en fait si".
Ceci étant dit, la 2ème formulation n'a pas beaucoup de sens s'il n'y a pas le contexte qui justifie un certain seuil.

L'utilisation de la particule "**ne**" change en effet le sens de la phrase, en complément de la position du verbe. Car la formulation "pas moins de" n'est pas utilisée comme une formulation négative ici, ce n'est pas une comparaison, c'est un fait.

Pour aller plus loin, en prenant les exemples de [ce lien](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4115) (je n'arrive pas a expliquer pourquoi certains exemples sont de type 1 ou 2)

> Malgré ce qu’elle prétend, je suis persuadé qu’elle n’a pas moins de trente ans.

- Type 1 (c'est la négation de "moins de trente ans")

> Ils n’attendaient pas moins de dix parents à la réunion.

- Type 2 (il y a exactement 10 parents, et c'est beaucoup)

> Cette île n’a pas moins de quarante kilomètres de circonférence.

- Type 2

> Les filles n’ont pas moins de projets d’avenir que les garçons.

- Type 1 (simple comparaison entre les projets de filles et garçons)

> Je n’en attendais pas moins de toi.

- Semblable au type 2. Cela veut dire "J'étais sur que t'en étais capable, je suis fier de toi"

> Malgré un horaire chargé, elle n’en continue pas moins d’accepter de nouveaux mandats.

- Ni l'un ni l'autre, ici le sens est "elle en continue néanmoins d’accepter [...]"

> La compagnie supprime encore pas moins de deux cents emplois.

- Type 2

> Marie-Claude a fait appel à pas moins de vingt personnes pour avoir de l’aide.

- Type 2

Comment: Effectivement, les deux formulations n'auraient pas exactement le même sens. Pour ce qui est de déterminer si la première est correcte, il semblerait effectivement qu'elle le soit. D'après ce que j'ai pu lire sur Internet de sources variées, on se passe de la particule adverbiale "ne" dans certains cas de "fausse négation". Voici ce que les québecois disent de la locution ["pas moins de"](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4115).

Comment: En effet, c'est la même chose en France. Je pense que la vraie différence est la position du verbe par rapport au "pas moins". J’édite ma réponse pour détailler ce sujet.